# Finding the electric potential energy when you know the joules and the charge

Tags: work, potential-energy

What equation do you need if you know both the amount of joules required for the work and the charge, to find the distance the charge has travelled and the electric potential energy at the point the charge will reach after the known amount of work?

Does this question make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> find the....electric potential energy at the point the charge will
> reach after the known amount of work?

Knowing the work $W$ in Joules that was done to move charge $Q$ gives you the *change* in electrical potential energy in moving the charge. It does not, however, tell you what the value of the electrical potential energy is after moving the charge because that depends on what point is assigned zero electrical potential energy. See the analogy for gravitational potential energy (GPE) discussed below.

> find the distance the charge has travelled...after the known amount of
> work?

In order to determine the distance traveled, you need information on the electric field in which the work was done. The work $W$ done on the charge $Q$ equals the average force $F$ exerted on the charge times the distance $d$ or

$$W=Fd$$

If we assume a uniform field of magnitude $E$, then $F=QE$ and

$$W=QEd$$

$$d=\frac{W}{QE}$$

To determine $d$ you need $E$.

**GPE ANALOGY:**

Let's say you do work to raise an object of mass $m$ a vertical distance of $h$. The work you do equals the change in gravitational potential energy (GPE) of $mgh$. But the value of the GPE at the height $h$ depends on where the GPE is assigned a value of zero, which can be arbitrary. Typically, for examples like this, the surface of the earth is assigned a GPE of zero.

If the surface of the earth is assigned a GPE of zero, then if you raised the object a height $h$ off the ground, both its GPE and change in GPE are $mgh$.

On the other hand, if the starting point of the object is $h_o$ above the ground where the GPE is assigned a value of zero its initial GPE is $mgh_o$. its GPE after raising the object a distance $h$ above $h_o$ is $mg(h+h_{o})$. Note, however its *change* in GPE is still $mgh$.

Hope this helps.